# DOMException: Failed to execute 'getAll' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, indexeddb

```
private get ctxMessage() {
    const messageTransaction = this.db.transaction('messages', 'readwrite');
    const messageStore = messageTransaction.objectStore('messages');
    return { messageTransaction, messageStore };
}


private async getAllMessage(message: Message) {
    const { messageStore ,messageTransaction } = this.ctxMessage;
    const result =  await messageStore.getAll();
    return result
}
```

Showing transaction is not active when I try to call **getAllMessage** method.

> I am using idb npm package

Answer (score 2):

The call to `getAll` must occur within the same event loop iteration as `db.transaction(...)` because a transaction completes when no pending requests are detected at the end of the current event loop iteration. This error occurs because you are trying to start an IDBRequest on a transaction that has already completed and is therefore no longer active. To fix the error, revise the code to ensure that `getAll` is called immediately after creating the transaction. One simple way to do this is to just create a new transaction every time you need to call `getAll`.